# Fill DropDownList with JsonData

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I haven't worked on Json before,its my first time and as expected I stucked at a point where I want to fill the DropDown with the JsonData.
Here What I am doing is I have an Xml which I am converting in Json like:

```
string xml = "<Root><Name>A</Name><Name>B</Name><Name>C</Name></Root>";
```

Then doing this to convert it into **JsonString**:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(Xml);
            string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

Currently my **View** is like:

```
<div>
        <input type="button" value="work" name="work" id="idwork" />
    </div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()), new {id="ddl_items" })
```

**Script**:

```
var ddl = $('#ddl_items');
    $('#idwork').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: {},
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (myJSONdata) {
  $(myJSONdata.Name).each(function () {
                        ddl.append(
                            $('<option/>', {
                                value: this.ReworkTunnelName
                            }).html(this.Nome)
    ..
    ..
    });
```

Now what I want to do is Fill the Dropdown with Names with the help of this JsonData.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up doing this and this is working Fine..

```
$('#idRework').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {},
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (myJSONdata) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(myJSONdata);                   
                    $.each(obj.Root.ReworkTunnelName, function (index, itemData) {
                        ddl.append($('<option></option>').val(itemData).html(itemData));

                    });

                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(myJSONdata, function ()
 {
  ddl.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", this.ReworkTunnelName).text(this.Nome));
 });
```

Edit

```
$.each(myJSONdata, function ()
 {
  ddl.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", this.ReworkTunnelName).attr("text",this.Nome));
 });

$.each(myJSONdata.Root, function ()
 {
  ddl.append($("<option></option>").attr("text", this.ReworkTunnelName));
 });
```

Comment: This is giving Uncaughtexception on .text(this.Nome)); saying object has no method text

Comment: @Farzi i have added another option as well, i am already using the first one and its works good with mvc drop down list.

Comment: Same exception as in case of text

Comment: @Farzi you need to debug and see if your drop down is supporting text property or not. In general it should be.

Comment: the Jsondata i am getting is in this form: "{"Root":{"ReworkTunnelName":["A","B","C"]}}" and i want to show A B C in the dropdown

Comment: @Farzi you are getting only one param in your jason so it can be either text or value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new javascript function and pass the dropdown id and json data as parameters in it.

Then you can parse json data as per your data structure. Further run a loop and add items in the select element.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can post a code that does that.

Comment: I was about to write the code. But I saw the answer by "Rex" and it was solving the problem. So leaving it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getJSON` method in jQuery :

```
$.getJSON("ActionMethodName", "", function (data) {
                $(data).each(function () {
                    $("<option>").val(this.ReworkTunnelName)
                                 .text(this.Nome)
                                 .appendTo("#ddl_items");
                });
});
```

HTML :

```
<select id="ddl_items">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each(myJSONdata, function (index, item) {  
   $('#ddl_items').get(0).options[$('#ddl_items').get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Text, item.Value);
});
```

Comment: yes.. there was one extra ")" near the "$('#ddl_items')". removed now.. Check the updated answer